# Need to remove a downvote :-(

Tags: support, down-votes

I accidentally cast a downvote on one of the answers to this question ([Computing $\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703706/computing-cos-frac-pi7)) and want to remove it.  I became aware of it too late and thus ask for help.

Comment: I edited the answer in question.